# Having trouble making a discord bot that direct messages @mentioned user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

trying to create a command for my bot where you can type /ping @user, and it then dm's mentioned user, as well as replies in chat with 'pong'

heres what i have so far:

```
async def cmd_ping(self, author, user_mentions):
    if not user_mentions:
        raise exceptions.CommandError("No users listed.", expire_in=20)
    else:
        usr = user_mentions[0]
        await self.safe_send_message(mention_user, "`pong!`")
        return Response(self.str.get('mentioned-user', "***{0}*** `pong`").format(usr.name,))
```

without await self.safe_send_message(mention_user, "`pong!`") the command works fine and replied with pong in chat

**edit** ~ i did not write this, i'm going off from another bot as i am not well knowledged in this field

```
async def safe_send_message(self, dest, content, **kwargs):
    tts = kwargs.pop('tts', False)
    quiet = kwargs.pop('quiet', False)
    expire_in = kwargs.pop('expire_in', 0)
    allow_none = kwargs.pop('allow_none', True)
    also_delete = kwargs.pop('also_delete', None)

    msg = None
    lfunc = log.debug if quiet else log.warning

    try:
        if content is not None or allow_none:
            if isinstance(content, discord.Embed):
                msg = await self.send_message(dest, embed=content)
            else:
                msg = await self.send_message(dest, content, tts=tts)

    except discord.Forbidden:
        lfunc("Cannot send message to \"%s\", no permission", dest.name)

    except discord.NotFound:
        lfunc("Cannot send message to \"%s\", invalid channel?", dest.name)

    except discord.HTTPException:
        if len(content) > DISCORD_MSG_CHAR_LIMIT:
            lfunc("Message is over the message size limit (%s)", DISCORD_MSG_CHAR_LIMIT)
        else:
            lfunc("Failed to send message")
            log.noise("Got HTTPException trying to send message to %s: %s", dest, content)

    finally:
        if msg and expire_in:
            asyncio.ensure_future(self._wait_delete_msg(msg, expire_in))

        if also_delete and isinstance(also_delete, discord.Message):
            asyncio.ensure_future(self._wait_delete_msg(also_delete, expire_in))

    return msg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def ping(user: discord.User):
    await bot.send_message(user, "Pong")
    await bot.say("Pong")

@ping.error
async def ping_error(ctx, error):  
    # You might have to play with the arguments here depending on your version of discord.py
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await bot.say("Could not find that user.")
```

I've tried to write the above for "async" branch, but you should know that there is also a "rewrite"  branch of `discord.py` that is more current and has better documentation, especially when it comes to the `commands` extension.

Did you write `safe_send_message`?  I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: Edited post ^^^

Answer (score 1):

This is my warn command. Try to use this as a template.

```python
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, userName: discord.User, *, message:str):
    await client.send_message(userName, "You have been warned for: {}".format(message))
    await client.say(":warning: __**{0} Has Been Warned!**__ :warning: Reason:{1} ".format(userName,message))
    pass
```