# Selecting User in client.send_message() from arg list

Tags: python, discord.py

Kind of hard to explain but I have this code:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith("!SAY"):
  args = message.content.split(" ")
  await client.send_message(args[1],"%s" % (" ".join(args[2:])))
```

Basically, what this does is when someone types !say the first arg should be a user

like:

```
!say @thepatchworkhoax#1024
```

and the next is:

```
!say @thepatchworkhoax#1024 random text
```

Using this the bot will send the user a message, of the random text.

But I need to find out the proper prefix to select the user from the list:

Aka:

```
 user.args[1]
```

If anyone knows this I would greatly appreciate the help.

FULL CODE :

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.upper().startswith("!PING"):
    userid = message.author.id
    await client.send_message(message.channel,"<@%s> Pong!" % userid)
  if message.content.upper().startswith("!SAY"):
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    await client.send_message(args[1],"%s" % (" ".join(args[2:])))
```

Comment: Incase unclear, user.arg[1] is an example of what I want, not a solution.

Comment: I think it'd be a lot easier for us and for yourself if you put your commands inside functions. You can do this with the command extension, see examples for both the async and rewrite branch [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/basic_bot.py). This way you can select parts of the message as parameters.

Comment: Without additional code there's not a lot of context to go on here. The code snippet you shared appears to inspect the message sent. Without more context, there's no way to know what other objects/variables are available for inspection. If I had to take a guess `message` only contains the message content, so you'll need to look at other variables available in the source to find the message's sender.

Comment: sorry Ill edit it into the full code

Comment: Also the message.content is just taking what the original person types, so arg 1 would be the username that they select and arg 2: would be all the text.

Comment: If you're interested in making this a command, you can look at the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076814/having-trouble-making-a-discord-bot-that-direct-messages-mentioned-user) that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use an event you could do something like

```
  if message.content.upper().startswith("!SAY"):
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    await client.send_message(message.mentions[0],'%s' % (' '.join(args[2:])))
```

But I suggest you look into using commands for this sort of functionality